# How to make image icon dimensions of a standard size?

Tags: images

I'm currently creating icons for 52 cards of a card game, and, using MS Paint and MS Office Picture Manager to crop a larger image which contains all the cards, and, resize the pictures so that each card is stored in a separate file i.e. `01.GIF` is Ace of Clubs up to `52.GIF` should be King of Spades.  I'm using Java 1.6 and Eclipse to code the application.

However, I have noticed that the manual cropping leads to a slight difference in the image size (when reading the image on MS Windows, so for example one image has dimensions of 73 x 98 - presumably pixels), while another image has dimensions of 73 x 97).

Any idea how to ensure that the dimensions are the same?

The images are available in a RAR file at http://bit.ly/dHKEsI.

The cards are `Ace, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King` of `Clubs,  Diamonds, Hearts, Spades` each.

Comment: I'd simply suggest **not** using MS Paint and MS Office Picture Manager if the crop sizes turn out to be wrong. Maybe try a decent program like [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) or even a trial of [Photoshop Elements](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshopel/), where you would be able to define a specific crop size.

Comment: You can do it by an application with java ;). try it. and for any help on your code ask in [StackOverFlow](http://stackoverflow.com/) or any help on your algorithms ask in [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)